# Great PDF Creators for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, pdf, pdfcreator

Im looking for a Great PDF CREATOR for the Mac, not just an editor, not a program that combines PDFs, but a PDF creator, I have looked at Adobe X Pro, but the price is high to say the least, so Im not getting that.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every application on the Mac that prints, is also a PDF creator. So, for example, you can use Pages or TextEdit to create PDFs.

To create a PDF, from any printable application:

1. Choose the menu item **File > Print...**
2. Click the PDF disclosure button on the bottom-left of the print panel
3. From the menu that appears choose either **Save as PDF...** or **Open PDF in Preview**

Using a combination of your chosen application and Preview you can accomplish most PDF creation tasks. One exception of note is PDF forms.